# How to set file/directory ownership/permissions in a Samba share on Windows using Python/.NET?

Tags: .net, python, windows, samba

I need to create directories and files in a Samba share on Windows, from a Python script. I can (and do) also use .NET 3.5 from Python. I would like to create these directories and files with certain owners and permissions. Can I achieve this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CACLS.exe to display or modify Access Control Lists (ACLs) for files and folders.  You can call this from Python with something like:

`result = os.popen("cacls " + '"' + theDirPath + '"')`

There is a good example of a Python script which sets up permissions [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/add-security-to-a-file.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was quick! Looking into cacls/icacls.

Comment: I have now tried to set permissions in the samba share with icacls and cacls. The former crashes, while the latter says "Access is denied". The cacls command I supplied was: cacls \\sh\home-test-0\test /P "arvenk:R". This command should be OK, no?